# SQL UPDATE based on TOP

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to update a date field based on a date field from another table and I was told it would be unique on two fields:  dept_no and unit.

So I did this and it worked fine:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.record_date =  SELECT TOP 1 t2.record_date
FROM     jkyearly t1
    INNER JOIN yearly_inspection t2 ON (t1.dept_no = t2.dept_no AND t1.unit = t2.unit) ORDER BY record_date DESC
```

But now, I found out the client gave me incorrect information (what a shock, right?).  There are multiple records in the yearly_inspection for each dept_no + unit combination, but I need to fill in the latest date for each of those combinations.  So I tried this:

```
UPDATE jkyearly
SET record_date =
  (SELECT TOP (1) record_date
   FROM            yearly_inspection AS t2
   WHERE        (dept_no = dept_no) AND (unit = unit)
   ORDER BY record_date DESC)
```

Well, that worked in that it updated the fields, but with only the one latest date for everything.  I need the latest date for each `dept_no + unit` combination.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: `order by` which `record_date`, `t1` or `t2`? Make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlated subquery.  You need to qualify *all* columns references, so:

```
UPDATE jkyearly
    SET record_date = (SELECT TOP (1) yi.record_date
                       FROM yearly_inspection yi
                       WHERE yi.dept_no = jkyearly.dept_no AND
                             yi.unit = jkyearly.unit
                       ORDER BY record_date DESC
                      );
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was the answer.  I *almost* had it, but didn't set up the aliases correctly.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
UPDATE jkyearly
SET record_date =
  (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(t2.record_date)
   FROM            yearly_inspection AS t2
   WHERE        (dept_no = dept_no) AND (unit = unit))
```

Comment: This gives the same top date for all records.  Comment above was the answer.